# Can't successfully call any external shell script in pipe with set -eo pipefail

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe, built-in

Suppose the following **test-pipefail.sh** batch:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eo pipefail
./echoer.sh | head -n1 >/dev/null
echo "Might work with pipefail"
for i in {1..100} ; do
    ./echoer.sh | head -n1 >/dev/null
done
echo "Stable work with pipefail"
```

With **echoer.sh** contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'head (GNU coreutils) 8.30'
echo 'GNU bash, version 5.0.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)'
exit 0
```

Expected results of **./test-pipefail.sh**:

```
Might work with pipefail
Stable work with pipefail
```

Actual behaviour:

```
Might work with pipefail
```

or (at random) with no output.

Writer program in pipe never fails if I'm using any binary utility instead of **echoer.sh**, but it always doesn't work (cause pipefail-script to exit) if writer is shell script (for example, ldd from glibc binary package).
Replacing execution (**./echoer.sh**) in **test-pipefail.sh** with sourcing (**. echoer.sh**) leads
to *increased probability of successful execution*, i.e. sometimes I'm getting

```
Stable work with pipefail
```

in **test-pipefail.sh** output.

head always returns success in such pipes.
Removing second echo in **echoer.sh** leads to successfull execution with both sourcing and execution in separate shell.

Comment: @KamilCuk stdbuf -oL ./echoer.sh shows same results as ./echoer.sh.
I wish to understand buffering problems in that case, because AFAIK line buffering is default when program outputs to shell (or pipe?).

Comment: `(or pipe?)` aaand block buffering is default when program outputs to a pipe.

Comment: @KamilCuk that makes sense, but any binary utility with same (default) buffering strategy in pipe leads to successful execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's reduce the problem down to the basics.  Consider:

```
$ (set -o pipefail; cat /dev/zero | head -c10; declare -p PIPESTATUS)
declare -a PIPESTATUS=([0]="141" [1]="0")
```

What happens is that, when `head` has had its fill, it finishes, closing the pipe.  The preceding command, `cat` in this case, gets a SIGPIPE (13) signal.  Consequently, it sets its exit code to 128+13=141 to indicate failure.

So, the issue is whether the first process is still running when the second process, `head`, finishes.  Sometimes, your `echoer.sh` is faster than `head` and sometimes it is slower.

Since we are multitasking two processes, the timing will always be variable.

#### Sourcing vs executing

> Replacing execution (`./echoer.sh`) in test-pipefail.sh with sourcing (`. echoer.sh`) leads to increased probability of successful execution

Sourcing eliminates the need to initialize a new shell which likely leads to faster execution and therefore greater likelihood of finishing before `head`.

#### Binary programs

> Writer program in pipe never fails if I'm using any binary utility
> instead of `echoer.sh`

My `cat` example above shows the opposite.  That is because the `cat /dev/zero` program will *never* finish, thus ensuring that it will eventually receive the SIGPIPE.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. That's really interesting point: while cat satisfies its pipe successor, it fails because it must work inifinite amount of time to success.

Answer (score 5):

I think the result depends on how fast the *writer* finishes. If it finishes very quickly then it has no chance to be sent with `SIGPIPE`.

For example:

```
[STEP 119] # hexdump -n100 /dev/urandom | head -n1; echo '$?'=$?
0000000 eea2 36e7 24d8 15de 620c e258 f9d8 f138
$?=0
[STEP 120] # hexdump -n1000 /dev/urandom | head -n1; echo '$?'=$?
0000000 cf81 dd51 1594 88b2 c9c1 6c8a bbbd c80f
$?=0
[STEP 121] # hexdump -n1000 /dev/urandom | head -n1; echo '$?'=$?
0000000 ef2d b2d3 1024 af9f ee1e a5e6 5528 699e
$?=0
[STEP 122] # hexdump -n2000 /dev/urandom | head -n1; echo '$?'=$?
0000000 d9f7 6a0d 633b c1f7 8928 cef8 3ea9 6f5a
$?=141
[STEP 123] # hexdump -n2000 /dev/urandom | head -n1; echo '$?'=$?
0000000 c044 dbb0 c227 1836 9fb5 f03b b2d1 0605
$?=141
[STEP 124] #
```

Comment: hexdump -n100000 /dev/urandom | head -n1; echo '$?'=$? # "always" prints $?=0 on my machine
Probabilistic approach is good, but what the hell is this? How should scripts with pipefail even work? Wasn't it a good practice in shell scripting? Or it is?

Comment: based on my understanding `pipefail` should be usually used where a command in pipeline may **logically** fail, rather than be killed by the too common seen `SIGPIPE` as in your example. or put it another way, use `pipefail` when you think it meets your real requirement.

Comment: your system is more powerful than mine. im using a small vm.